# Collections.sort() doesn't merge duplicates. Do I alternative from any other library?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I want to merge the duplicates while sorting a list. But `Collections.sort()` doesn't help with that. Also most of the portions of my list are already sorted, so is there any other libray method that provides me sorting along with merging of duplicates ?

Comment: use `Set` for removing duplicates

Answer (score 7):

```
Set<Foo> sortedAndMerged = new TreeSet<Foo>(myFooComparator);
sortedAndMerged.addAll(list);
```

That's it. Nothing more needed.
The explanation of what a Set and what a TreeSet are is available in their javadoc.

Note that duplicate, in this context, means "which, when compared using the comparator, are considered equal".

Comment: Rather than creating a new `Set` out of the list, dont you think it would be better to just iterate over the sorted list once & check if the next item is duplicate of current item & if not, then add it to new list. Looks more performant to me than creating a set. what do you think ?

Comment: I assumed the OP wanted a sorted collection without duplicates, not necessarily a List. Newbies often assume that List is the only existing collection.

Comment: Both would be O(n log(n)). It would have to be measured. Usually, it doesn't matter because usually, the collections are so small that the time needed to sort and de-duplicate them is negligible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` to store data. There is a Implementation call `Tree-Set` which is a sorted set. You can simply use that.

More about [treeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `TreeSet` from the `Collection` bcoz it will automatically remove the duplicate element and sort the element.

Answer (score 1):

What i can conclude is, that you want to sort a List which has duplicates present in it. You are expecting a simple library function for both of these tasks.
As far as I know, there is no such library function using which you can remove duplicates and sort it alsol; in case of Lists.

Preferrably, you can copy the List contents in a set. Since, TreeSets is sorted, you will not need to sort it explicitly unless and until you want on the basis of some object or specific attribute. This would be an apt solution since, SETS cannot have duplicates where as LISTS can.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestList {

    public TreeSet copySet(List ls) {
        TreeSet s = new TreeSet();
        s.addAll(ls);
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List ls = new ArrayList();
        ls.add(1);
        ls.add(1);
        ls.add(2);
        ls.add(5);
        ls.add(4);
        ls.add(4);

        TestList obj = new TestList();
        TreeSet s1 = obj.copySet(ls);
        System.out.println(ls);
        System.out.println(s1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Sets are not sorted. Only SortedSets are sorted. And HashSet is not a SortedSet. Also, generics exist since Java 5, and we're almost at Java 8. You shouldn't use raw types.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. I wrote this jst to mock up the functionality. Generics are a must. Thanks